# How to render BULLET character in React Native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Im trying to format data that has to be displayed on `<Text>`. Here is my `formatData()` method:

```
getFormattedData = (idA, idB) => {
    var formattedData = "";
    if (idA != null && idA != "") {
        formattedData = formattedData + "&#8226;" + " " + idA
    }
    if (idB != null && idB != "") {
        formattedData = formattedData + "&#8226;" + " " + idB
    }
    return formattedData;
};
```

But in view, this is rendered as `ABC &#8226; DEF`. And not as `ABC • DEF`

When I use `\u2B24` the bullet is very big and when using `\2022`, just the code is displayed.

How to render `•` with `getFormattedData()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To parse HTML Entities you can use the npm module [html-entities](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-entities).

```
import { Html5Entities } from 'html-entities'; 

render() {
    const entities = new Html5Entities();
    return (
      <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
        <View>
        <Text> {entities.decode('&#8226;')} </Text>
        </View>
      </SafeAreaView>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

This works for me,

```
getFormattedData = (idA, idB) => {
    var formattedData = "";
    if (idA != null && idA != "") {
        formattedData = <div>{formattedData}&#8226;{idA}</div>
    }
    if (idB != null && idB != "") {
        formattedData = <div>{formattedData}&#8226;{idB}</div>
    }
    return formattedData;
};

render() {
    return (
        <div>{this.getFormattedData(12,"abc")}</div>
    );
  }
```

Output:

•12

•abc

Comment: Question was about React Native, not React.